# upgrade to 2.78

Tags: installation

I have been using Blender for almost 2 years and always upgrade to the latest version and have never had a problem until now.
I just tried to upgrade to 2.78 and this is the message I received when I try to run Blender(Program can,t start because sdll2.dll is missing from your computer) I was going to try installing again but I do not want to lose my custom settings. What should I do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a backup folder of 2.76on my desktop so I copied the sdll2.dll and pasted it in the blender folder and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and simply installing it again worked. Also no settings or similar got lost so it wasn't really necessary to backup the Blender folder. But as you stated did copying it from an older version work too.

Answer (score 1):

This is posted below the install file.

[image]